# Are there ways of recognizing fonts used in document

Tags: fonts

I am reading the book *Real Mathematical Analysis* by Pugh, and on p.443 it uses a special letter (seems to be G):
[image: p.443, see line 6]

I am interested in the font used but I cannot find it.

So, here're two questions:

- Does anyone know which font the author is using?
- Is there a software or tool which can recognize fonts, or is there a document which documents all fonts available for LaTeX?

Comment: Are you aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)?

Comment: I tried recognizing font using PDF edit software but only got a string "MxrqrnWxqxycCsc" which I have no idea what it is.

Comment: The general font is Computer Modern; the calligraphic letters are Euler. The horrible symbols are some kind of Sütterlin, I believe.

Comment: @egreg -- Not Sütterlin -- that resembles the lowercase "g" (formerly?) taught to U.S. schoolchildren.  The "G" shown here (yes, it *is* a "G") is a particularly "crabbed" version of the uppercase "G" in that same alphabet.  [Here are pictures of some typical examples.](https://www.drawyourworld.com/blog/examples-of-handwriting-styles.html)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was not far, then. ;-) A horrible symbol nonetheless.

Comment: @egreg -- You get no argument from me re "horrible".  (Even *my* handwriting isn't that bad!)